# Multi-row selection on Lazy Loaded jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm using a lazy loaded(Deferred) jQuery Datatable and trying to add multi-row selection too. However, when I click on another page of the datatable, the selected rows from the previous page was cleared.

```
// this is how to multi-select
$('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function() 
  {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
```

Lint to deffered loading datatable: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

Note* Instead of using the server-side processing script, I've created a php function for datatable ajax.

The result I wanted is to multi-row select the lazy loaded jQuery datatable on each pages without being cleared when navigated to another page.

Anyone experienced the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found an answer already. There's jQuery datable callback called "`createdRow`". Made a conditional statement to acquire the result I needed.

Here's the link to it: https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow